# Exception reading Wifi/3G State

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-wifi, 3g, cellular-network

Hi I have the following code that reads Network/Wifi state:

```
public String getMacAddress() {
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    return wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
}
```

This throws

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10032 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
```

And

```
public boolean is3G() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return !(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(
            ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || connectivityManager
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED);
}
```

This throws

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10032 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
```

Before someone tell me about the permissions, that is my Manifest (the relevant part):

```
<manifest> 
   <!-- usual tags for activitys... etc.. -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've mispelled the latest 2 permissions:

useR-permission instead of useS-permission

Answer (score 3):

Your manifest permissions are wrong.

you have user-permission instead of uses-permission